# Static call from singleton

Tags: php, singleton, static-methods

I have a singleton loaded with some data from cache
Must be a  singleton to load   cache only once

```php
class myClass {
use MyTrait ;
 private static $_file = 'my_file';
 private static $instance;
 private function __construct()
    {
       self::loadCache();
       register_shutdown_function(function() {
       self::save();
       });
    }

    
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

and a trait

```php
trait MyTrait
{
    
    protected static $config = false;
     public static function loadCache(){
         static::$config = Cache::Instance()->get(static::$_file);
    }
public static function get ($name){

return self::$config[$name];
}
 public static function save()
    {
        Cache::Instance()->set(static::$_file, self::list());
            
        
    }
```

```php
 MyClass::getInstance()::get($id);
```

is there any drawbacks in using this  form ?
is there  any other (better ? )  options ?
Another option is to refactor get method and call getInstance inside  get

```php
public static function get ($name){

return self::getInstance()::$config[$name];
}
 MyClass::get($id);
```

But  this will break the some implementation  inside a pure static class that don't have  getInstance method and reuse trait myTrait

```php
class Config {
use myTrait;
}
 Config::get('my_theme_config');
```

Comment: Welcome. Why would you use a singleton (which is more often than not a sign of bad design, btw) then use static properties/methods? Where is your trait used? Please explain what the class/trait are supposed to do exactly (what their goal is), and please also reformat your code in the process.

Comment: i can use that myTrait inside any class that have same need to store some 'items' as array internally even it is a  static class or a singleton .  Why singleton? The 'items' must be loaded only once

Comment: I don't see where you are defining $instance as a property of myClass, but I'm guessing it's a private static property.  In which case, I think the correct usage would be: myClass()::getInstance()->get($id);

Comment: edited . stack  don't allow  entire  class here 
 myClass::getInstance()->get($id); do not work since 'get' it's  static inside trait